# Prove that every natural number $n >6$ can be written as a sum $a+b$ where $a, b∈\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}$ and$ \gcd(a, b) = 1$

Tags: induction, gcd-and-lcm

Is this the correct approach to this problem:
I tried induction. 
This is what the professor said: Hint:  Treat the cases $n$ even and odd separately.

---

### Inductive hypothesis:

$n=a+b$ for $n>6$

### Base case

Let $n = 7$. Then $3+4=7$ where $3,4$ have a gccd of $1$.

### Induction Step

Induction Step:
Prove: $n+1=a+b$

Case 1: Let $a$ be $a + 1$. This is possible because $a$ is in the natural numbers.
So $a+b+1=n+1$. By the inductive hypothesis $n=a+b$ so we can substitute it. Therefore $n+1=n+1$.

Case 2: Let $b$ be $b+1$. 
This is symmetrical to case one.

Comment: Induction is not a very good approach for this problem.  Here are some hints:  $\gcd(k, k+1) = 1$ and $\gcd(2k + 1, 2k+3) = 1$

Comment: Try following the professors hint.  The odd case is the easiest.  If you are doing even and odd separately, it doesn't really make sense to do induction

Comment: You have not shown anything about keeping the numbers coprime.  The solution I spot is: In the case that $n$ is odd, $n=2+(n-2)$, noting that $\gcd(2,n-2)=1$.  In the case that $n$ is a multiple of $4$, $n=(\frac{n}{2}-1)+(\frac{n}{2}+1)$.  A different example would need to be used in the case that $n$ is a multiple of $2$ but not a multiple of $4$...

Comment: “Let $a$ be $a+1$.” This doesn't make any sense.  I think what you mean is that if $n=a+b$, where the gcd of $a$ and $b$ is 1, then $n+1 = (a+1) + b$.  But you can't call it $a$ again; $a$ has been taken.  More to the point: How do you know that the gcd of $a+1$ and $b$ is also 1?  What if $n=11$, $a=9$, and $b=2$?  Then $n+1=12$, $a+1=10$, and suddenly the gcd is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually induction is not needed. Assuming $n>6$ we have that $\varphi(n)$ is even and $\geq 4$.
Once we pick some $a\in[1,n-1]$ which is coprime with $n$ we also have that $b=n-a$ is coprime with $n$, and $a,b$ cannot have common divisors except $1$, since a non-trivial common divisor of $a,b$ would be a non-trivial common divisor of $a,n$.

In particular, it is enough to pick $a$ as the smallest prime $\nmid n$ and $b$ as $n-a$.